# R plumber Api on cloud foundry deployment got stuck

Tags: r, cloud-foundry

I have 3 files in a folder - init.r, myapp.r and manifest.yml.

Manifest file contains information for deployment on cloud foundry. I am using **https://github.com/beibeiyang/cf-buildpack-r.git** buildpack for deployment.

myapp.r contains a very simple function that returns output whatever it gets as input and it is using get request with @ annotation.

```
#* @get /mypath
abc <- function(input1){
  return(input1)
}
```

init.r contains following code:

```
install.packages("plumber")
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("myapp.r")
r$run(port=8056)
```

It is fine when I run this code in local using R studio. But when I deploy it to cloud foundry, it got stuck after saying: **Starting server to listen on port (8056 or any other port)**. It waited for 15 minutes and failed to start. No progress after that. Anyone has any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is monitored by a health checker. With its default setting of `port` (see `--health-check-type` option of `cf push`), it repeatedly tries to connect to the app container's default port (8080) to check if your app has started successfully. And eventually it times out, as your app is not responding to requests on that port.

Try again with port 8080 instead of 8056, or better, the port number passed in to your app through the `PORT` environment variable (see http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#PORT).